# Netbeans 8.0.2 project with Jersey and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I have a Netbeans project in 8.0.2. For various reasons, I am not using Maven.

I have some REST resource methods that return Map and some that return a complex POJO. These are to be converted to JSON.

From reading around, I gather that the Moxy default plugin cannot stream these to JSON and I would be better off using Jackson.

My question is:
What are the various Jackson jars that I require ? Where do I get those from ? Remember, I am not using Maven, so I can't just add a dependency in pom.xml to jersey-media-json-jackson and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually download the various Jackson release JARs from Maven Central [via GitHub](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson); see the projects' respective Downloads page. Since you're not using dependency management you'll need to manually ensure that all of Jackson's dependencies are satisfied (have fun!).

You'll need *at least*

- [jackson-core](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/) – [downloads page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki#download)
- [jackson-jaxrs-providers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/) – [downloads page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/wiki#downloads)

Comment: It's probably easier for me to recreate my projects to use maven - thanks for the steer.